# How to delay all tomcat server request

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I want to delay all `Tomcat` server request for the testing purpose. 
I've been calling `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)`  from the `servlet` to make the delay. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Why? Testing what?

Comment: @EJP : I've wrote a small API using the `Servlet`. So i need to know how it's going to act in the client side if there's any delay in the network. Without the delay, i can't even see the progress dialogue on the screen. Everything works very fast, because it's the `localhost` the API runs. Sooo, i need to mock a delay in the API side. clear ?

Answer (score 3):

You could make a `javax.servlet.Filter` that introduces the delay. That way you don't have to add the `Thread.sleep()` to every servlet manually, and you can introduce additional logic (such as random delay) in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use an external reverse proxy like nginx using the echo module.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/echo/#